# Loaded image showing broken image symbol on backend and frontend

Tags: magento-1.9, product-images, image-upload, ce-1.9.2.2

When I load a new image to product or page I get a broken image symbol on backend and frontend. Previous loaded images in the storage root are able to load fine. New images add to storage root look fine in storage root file but when uploaded the same broken image symbol. Same happening on all 3 magento sites. Loaded images are going in the media folder and look fine same as all previous loaded images that are working fine on sites.

Comment: please add some images

Comment: i am getting the same issue but only in admin panel , on frontend images are working properly

Answer (score 2):

Resulted from upgrade to 1.9.2.3 with security patch.
To fix this issue I had to revert change the permissions to more realistic values, 775 for folders and 644 for files. These can be changed here;

lib/Varien/File/Uploader.php

line 219, change 0640 to 0644
line 541, change 0750 to 0755

Comment: Check this: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/105505/images-not-displayed-in-admin-after-manual-upload-in-magento-1-9-1/105507#105507

Comment: Also works for Magento 1.8.1 CE! Same lines.

Answer (score -1):

Resulted from upgrade to 1.9.2.3 with security patch. To fix this issue I had to revert change the permissions to more realistic values, 775 for folders and 644 for files. These can be changed here;

lib/Varien/File/Uploader.php

Didn't work tested in on my website

Comment: Sorry, worked fine for me on 4 different magento sites.